# how to properly use dinamic id name in vue v-for?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

i'm trying to iterate a div within a v-for.
and i'm trying to use the index parameter for dynamic div id assignment, but i don't know how to properly use it...

Least i am using bootstrap collapse to assign a data-target to the rendered div.
It doesn't work.

**Here the code:**

```
                '<div class="servizioInlista" v-for="(servizio,index) in servizi.lineaGialla.servizi">'+
                        '<div class="row">'+
                            '<div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 nopadding">'+
                                '<h4 class="blu">{{servizio.nomeServizio}}</h4>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4>"'+
                                '<span class="pull-right nomargin"  v-on:click="mostraServiziGiallo" v-bind:class="[GiallaTutti ? \'minus\' : !GiallaTutti,\'plus\']" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#singoloGialla.index"></span>'+                           
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div v-bind:id="singoloGialla.index" class="row">'+
                            '<p>{{servizio.descrizione}}</p>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
```

Comment: in the console i have the following message:
[Vue warn]: Property or method "singoloGialla" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want something like this:

```
<div v-bind:id="'singoloGialla-' + index" class="row">
  <p>{{servizio.descrizione}}</p>
</div>
```

and

```
< ... v-bind:data-target="'#singoloGialla-' + index">
```

So, we are taking the string `'singoloGialla-'` and concatenating it with the the dynamic value of the `index` variable. When we use the `+` operator to concatenate a string and a number, the number is first converted to a string, then concatenated to the existing string. This is not Vue specific, but normal JavaScript behavior.

Comment: yeah, i have tried before but i have the same message from vue.

I'm using this binding on a component anyway so the script is formatted in this way:

data-toggle="collapse" data-target="\'#singoloGialla-\'+index"

Comment: Do you have `singoloGialla` defined and returned in the `data` function of your component? That message is not about your `index` variable, by the way. Vue thinks `singoloGialla` is a variable.

Comment: No, singoloGialla is only a div id name... must i define it as a empty object in data?

Comment: OK. So, you should make sure Vue thinks it is a string. Currently, you seem to be escaping the single quote so it doesn't become a string, and no, in that case I don't think you should define it in data.